# What can be said of one whose bum rises before their shoulders/bar during barbell squats?

Tags: weightlifting, squats, barbell, technique

I’ve noticed that often while I’m doing barbell back squats, if the weight is on the heavier side, at a certain point I will begin to struggle a little bit, and at the bottom as I’m starting to come back up, my bum will begin to rise a bit while the bar stays stationary, meaning that my spine/back will begin to approach a slightly more horizontal angle. In other words, my knees will begin to straighten, but instead of the bar being raised upward, my waist will begin to bend a bit more to compensate, so that all that happens is that my bum begins to stick out backwards a bit more. After this happens to a little extent then the squat starts channeling upward again, and my hips will begin to extend together with my knees so that I end up standing.

What can said of this? Is my weight too high? Do I need to adjust my technique? Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like your form is shifting, moving the weight from you quads to more on your glutes. You're likely then able to complete the rep because the glutes are the stronger muscle. Provided you're doing it with good and safe form, that is a valid exercise. Keeping mostly straight legs and just hinging at the hip is a glute exercise called good mornings and can be useful if done right. If you are specifically looking to improve and get strong at squat though, you need to do squats, look forward and keep your back tight and your chest up.

Like you said yourself it is most likely because you're going too heavy. If you like lifting heavy, and some people do, I myself am one such person, I would recommend reducing the load to a weight with which you can do at least 4 good reps with proper form and just work from there. For example, a good method, and essentially the basis for progressive overload, is to find a weight that gives you 4 good reps. Keep working with that until you can do 6+ reps with that weight, at that point up the weight slightly until you can only get 4 reps again (still with good form) and just repeat that cycle.